# Spring Websocket with interceptor executes preSend when connection is closed

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I am using Interceptor to get Authorization headers but the presend method is executing both when connection is establishing and when it is closed. The problem is that when it is closed the headers throw null exception should I check for null first or there is a better way to stop the connection so the preSend method is not executed? My config:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addEndpoint("/api/chat/message")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(getWebSocketInterceptor());
}
private WebSocketInterceptor getWebSocketInterceptor(){
    return new WebSocketInterceptor();
}
```

My WebSocketInterceptor:

```
public class WebSocketInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor, HandshakeInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
        MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = headers.get(StompHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS,MultiValueMap.class);
            for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> head : multiValueMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(head.getKey());
            if(head.getKey().equals("Authorization")){
                System.out.println(head.getValue());
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found How I can check the connection type in the preSend and also just take the headers from the StompHeaderAccessor:

```
StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
        MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
    List<String> authorization1 = accessor.getNativeHeader("Authorization");
}
```